# Node.js/Express.js - How to render a remote HTML file to the client?

Tags: html, node.js, express, cdn

I am currently in the process of making a blog website, writers for this website have the ability to upload AMP HTML files and the assets required for does files to work. Both the html file and their assets get sent to our CDN.

Now, when a client visits the website in the link example.com/13215 the server gets the parameter 13215 and checks what post it refers to in the database and retrieves the link to the HTML file. How can I send this HTML file to the front end with Node.js/Express.js even though it is a remote file.

Just copy pasting the URL into `response.sendFile()` and `response.render()` functions just throws errors. I thought about reading the file contents then writing them to a file then sending them to the client but I don't think that's a good idea performance wise.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If its a say pdf file, then the raw CDN should work

Comment: Does `http://example.com/13215` correspond to some different URL from the CDN?  If so, you can redirect the client to that URL.  If not, then perhaps your server needs to fetch the file from the CDN itself so it can then render it and then return the rendered HTML as the response to the original HTTP request.

Comment: @SeifKhalid in this situation I think you can either read the page and send its contents back (as you mentioned). Another approach could be to try with `node-http-proxy` to forward web requests., but depending on the way you retrieve the URL I'm afraid this may end up as a quite hacky solution.

Comment: What do you guys think  about storing the html contents in the database straight away and only the assets in the CDN?

Comment: @SeifKhalid - If your server needs to use the HTML file as a template (to fill in data) then it needs to be stored on your server somewhere.  It could be just stored in the local file system or in a database.  The file system might be more efficient for storing files.  If the HTML file is just a plain HTML file, then you can keep it on the CDN and redirect to it from your server.  Note: if it's third party content and you're storing it on your server and processing it as a template on your server, you will have evaluate security issues with your chosen template system.

Comment: @SeifKhalid did you ever solve this problem? I am trying to do something very similar now.